# What is the pythonic/idiomatic way of filtering the output of a generator expression?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suppose we have a generator expression, perhaps a simple one, but not necessarily so:

```py
(function(x) for x in values)
```

What is the preferred way to filter the values generated by this generator expression? I.e. we don't want to filter on the value of `x`, but on the value of `function(x)`?

Of course

```py
# this only filters on the inputs to the function, not on its results
(function(x) for x in values if _some_condition_expr_)
```

I presume that the following would be most pythonic (incidentally also getting rid of the generator expression itself):

```py
_ = lambda x: x  # simple filter for truthy values

filter(_, map(function, values))           # <<< is this the best we can do?
# or
filter(_, (generator_expression_contents_here))
```

- as opposed to this abomination:

```py
(y for y in (function(x) for x in values) if y)
```

Is there something I'm missing in generator expressions that would allow filtering the result without nesting expressions etc.? In other words, is the `filter(map())` approach the best we can do? I'm not trying to find something esoteric, just making sure that I'm not missing some cleaner or more Pythonic way of doing it.

AFAIK, Python doesn't come with an identity function (`_` above), nor with an `is_true` function.

Comment: `bool` is the equivalent to `is_true`, although `filter` actually special cases that with `None`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is one of the use-cases proposed for assignment expressions:

```
>>> def f(x):
...     return x % 3
... 
>>> g = (fx for x in range(10) if (fx := f(x)))
>>> list(g)
[1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2]
```

Adapted from [*Simplifying list comprehensions*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/#simplifying-list-comprehensions) in PEP 572.

This requires Python 3.8+. If you're using an earlier version of Python, or you just find assignment expressions ugly, then chaining generators is a fine alternative:

```
>>> g1 = (f(x) for x in range(10))
>>> g2 = (x for x in g1 if x)
>>> list(g2)
[1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2]
```

Note that simply [filtering on truthy values is supported directly](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) by using `None` instead of a callable:

```
>>> list(filter(None, range(3)))
[1, 2]
```

So you could use `filter(None, map(f, vals))` to similar effect.

Comment: Awesome ideas, and I didn't know about filtering on truthy values directly. Cool!

Answer (score 7):

It's a matter of debate as to whether this is better, but `:=` can be used here:

```
filtered = (res for val in values if (res := function(val)))
```

The result of the function is assigned to `res`, that result is used as the predicate, then `res` is available to be used on the left.

Comment: Note that this assigns to `res` in the scope *containing* the original generator expression, not the generator's own scope. Assignment expressions are weird like that.

Comment: Did you fetch any values from the generator, or just create it? It won't assign `res` until at least one iteration runs.

Comment: Well, I just tested it, and the assignment did happen in the containing scope. Also see the relevant section of [PEP 572](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/#scope-of-the-target): "There is one special case: an assignment expression occurring in a list, set or dict comprehension or in a generator expression (below collectively referred to as "comprehensions") binds the target in the containing scope, honoring a nonlocal or global declaration for the target in that scope, if one exists."

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica It's something funky with the REPL. If I produce the generator in a script, then force it in a REPL, `res` isn't in scope. It's fine if I do everything in the script though.

Comment: @user2357112 Try it inside a function scope.  https://replit.com/@wimglenn/assex#main.py

Comment: @wim: You didn't run the generator.

Comment:  fixed the repl

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use `filter`, then the cleanest way is to just write another generator expression. If syntactically nested generators are an abomination, then name them instead of nesting them:

```py
bar = (some_function(x) for x in foo)
baz = (y for y in bar if some_condition(y))
```

Note that you shouldn't use `bar` for anything else, since it can only be consumed once, and `baz` wants to consume it.

Answer (score 3):

You can iterate over the mapped values instead in your generator expression:

```
(y for y in map(function, values) if y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `itertools.filterfalse` makes it perform well, since the interpreter is not used to iterate:

```
itertools.filterfalse(operator.__not__, map(function, input_values))
```

Thus:

```
def filtertrue_map(function, iterable):
    return itertools.filterfalse(operator.__not__, map(function, iterable))
```